# Django reverse issue

Tags: python, django

I have the following `url.py` in my app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^save_dropbox_files/$', views.save_dropbox_files, name='save_dropbox_files'),
    url(r'^transfer_files/$', views.show_files_to_transfer, name='show_files_to_transfer'),
    url(r'^upload/(?P<token>[^/]+)$', views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Now I am trying to implement the `get_absolute_url()` function in my model like so:

```
class YoutubeToken(models.Model):
    userid = models.TextField()
    access_token = models.TextField()
    refresh_token = models.TextField(default='None', null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('upload', kwargs={'token': self.userid})
```

I'm trying to call it from another model like so (`youtube` is the model, apparently):

```
next = youtube.get_absolute_url()
```

However, I am getting the error `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '()'`, what is wrong with the above code?
My expected output is something like `/upload/token1234`.

---

The complete traceback (I have imported the models in Django's shell and the userid is not null):

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'token': u'1234'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: how you call that URL in the template ? can you show us that code ?

Comment: @shotgunner: Not in the template, but see the updated question.

Comment: Can you show the full error and traceback?

Comment: It can't find any url by the name `upload`, maybe because you're using a namespace? Please show your root urlconf where you include these urls.

Comment: @knbk: Transform your comment into an answer (the missing namespace was the problem) for me to accept it. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction, with `reverse('youtube:upload')` it works flawlessly!